# Powershell to manipulate file by removing unwanted rows

Tags: powershell

How to write powershell scripts that can manipulate file from below format

```
AREA: MAC
SUB_AREA: MAB
AREA_CODE: MA1
SUB_AREA_CODE: MA11
YEAR: 2015
VERSION: 1

---------------------------------------------------------------------
|column1|column2|cloumn3.............|last column
|--------------------------------------------------------------------
|Data1|Data2.........................|last data
|Data1|Data2.........................|last data
---------------------------------------------------------------------
AREA: MACC
SUB_AREA: MABB
AREA_CODE: MAC1
SUB_AREA_CODE: MAB11
YEAR: 2015
VERSION: 1

---------------------------------------------------------------------
|column1|column2|cloumn3.............|last column
|--------------------------------------------------------------------
|Data1|Data2.........................|last data
|Data1|Data2.........................|last data
---------------------------------------------------------------------

AREA: MACC
SUB_AREA: MABB
AREA_CODE: MAC1
SUB_AREA_CODE: MAB11
YEAR: 2016
VERSION: 2

---------------------------------------------------------------------
|column1|column2|cloumn3.............|last column
|--------------------------------------------------------------------
|Data1|Data2.........................|last data
|Data1|Data2.........................|last data
|--------------------------------------------------------------------
|*| 
| |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To

```
|column1|column2|cloumn3.............|last column
|Data1|Data2.........................|last data
|Data1|Data2.........................|last data
```

Rules are:
I only need the first column header from the file and append the data until the end of the data and delete last four rows from the file. Below sample screenshot.

Original file

[image]

Expected file

[image]

This is the code, how to rewrite the code so it exclude duplicate header in the file ? I only want the column header appear at the top of the line and only once.

```
$path = "D:\PowerShell\PC.TXT"
$outPath = "D:\PowerShell\Output\PC_Format.TXT"
$d = Get-Content -path $path
$d | Select-String -Pattern '^\|[^-]+' -allmatches |
Out-File -width 10000 -filepath $outPath
```

Comment: Can you show us _anything_ you have tried to get this? It would be easier if you included the raw text instead of pictures for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are interested only about rows that begin with pipe char `|` not followed by a dash `-`. How about filtering data with simply matching rows that begin with pipe and non-dash? Like so,

```
$d = get-content "c:\myDataFile.txt"
$d | Select-String -Pattern '^\|[^-]+' -allmatches

|column1|column2|cloumn3.............|last column
|Data1|Data2.........................|last data
|Data1|Data2.........................|last data
|column1|column2|cloumn3.............|last column
|Data1|Data2.........................|last data
|Data1|Data2.........................|last data
|column1|column2|cloumn3.............|last column
|Data1|Data2.........................|last data
|Data1|Data2.........................|last data
|*|
| |
```

Comment: The column header should occurs at the top of the row and only once.